# IQueryable convertions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, iqueryable

Why is conversion in line 'OK' possible, while not on line 'NOT OK'?

```
var queryable = new int[]{1, 2, 3}.AsQueryable();

var x = (Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>>>)(() => (from c in queryable select c));

var yy = (Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>>>)x;  // NOT OK (does not compile)
var zz = (Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>>>)(() => (from c in queryable select c)); // OK
```

Update: The error message is:

> Cannot convert type
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.Linq.IQueryable<int>>>`
>   to
>   '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>>`>'

Comment: provide the proper error message.

Comment: For a complete tutorial on covariance look here: [MSDN: Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Expression` is a class and `IEnumerable` is an interface. And classes are not covariant while interfaces and delegates are.

That means that you can't convert an `Expression<A>` to `Expression<B>` even if B is a base class of A.

So if this line:

```
() => (from c in queryable select c)
```

returns

```
Func<IQueryable<int>>
```

it can be converted to a

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>>
```

but if you already have

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>>>
```

it **can't** be converted into

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>>>
```

Comment: @l3arnon: you said *IEnumerable and IQueryable are already covariant*, that made me rethink the whole thing. You're right, sir!

Comment: @pid `Func` is as well. You can see that it uses the `in` or `out` keywords in the type definition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And how is lambda represented? I thought that either as Func<IQueryable<int>> or Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>>> .

Comment: @user3284063 There's a difference. Expression represents an expression tree mostly used to create some kind of query (like sql). `Func` and `Action` are actual delegates to a compiled method.

Comment: So what would be the path of convertions in the line 'OK' that type checker does? Since lambda can only (?) be represented as Expression or Func (and only Func's result is contravariant/out) it must first instantiate it as Func, but what comes next?

Comment: @user3284063 there isn't really a conversion. `(() => (from c in queryable select c))` on itself is something the compiler doesn't understand. when you tell it what to do with it (Expression or Func) it creates an expression tree or delegate accordingly.

Comment: Ok, just last question: since typechecker does not protest, there must be some proof of type correctness behind the scene, right? Does that mean that typechecker can reason more than it could be reasoned from types declaration? I am asking  because I don't understand the path of reasoning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47042/discussion-between-i3arnon-and-user3284063)

Answer (score 1):

`Expression<T>` is a class and is therefore not covariant.

You can do the following:

```
Func<IQueryable<int>> qf = () => queryable.Select(c => c);
Func<IEnumerable<int>> ef = qf;
```

however, since classes are not covariant in C#, you cannot assign an `Expression<T>` to an `Expression<U>` even if you can assign an instance of `T` to `U`;